# Updating a model using Entity Framework Core is updating another values

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

When I try to update a model using Entity Framework Core, it is deleting existing values of different columns in a same row. Please help.

I was trying to update a few columns but it's deleting existing columns info also.

Comment: You need to **SHOW US** stuff! Like your **code**, the data structure involved, the values before and after the update ...... we cannot just plain **GUESS** what your problems could be! You need to **help us help you!**

Comment: it would be indeed useful if you can share at least your code for updating columns.

Comment: The more info you can give us the easier it is for us to help you!